# What is the difference between Conversations / Threads / Posts in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, exchangewebservices

I am looking to use the Exchange API for conversations and feeling confused between the difference between conversations and threads. There is no documentation available around the same. Can someone please help to explain the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be familiar with Outlook entities to understand these terms better.

### Conversations

The [Conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.conversation) object is an abstract, aggregated object. Although a conversation can include items of different types, the Conversation object does not correspond to a particular underlying MAPI IMessage object.

A conversation represents one or more items in one or more folders and stores. If you move an item in a conversation to the Deleted Items folder and subsequently enumerate the conversation by using the `GetChildren`, `GetRootItems`, or `GetTable` method, the item will not be included in the returned object.

To obtain a `Conversation` object for an existing conversation, use the `GetConversation` method of the item.

Threads and Conversations are interchangeable. Sometimes in the UI may see a column named as threads. But from the developer point of view, it is still a conversation. Posts are items in the conversation.